# Disable Windows Recycle Bin delete confirmation in C#

Tags: c#, windows, recycle-bin, shell32

I am creating a small program which has a few functionalities to make my PC "feel better".
One of those functionalities is emptying my recycle bin.

I am using the following code for that:

```
enum RecycleFlags : uint
{
    SHERB_NOCONFIRMATION = 0x00000001, // No empty confirmation
    SHERB_NOPROGRESSUI = 0x00000002, // No progress tracking
    SHERB_NOSOUND = 0x00000004 // No sound on completion
}

[DllImport("Shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern uint SHEmptyRecycleBin(IntPtr hwnd, string pszRootPath, RecycleFlags dwFlags);

private bool IsEmpty()
{
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    Folder recycleBin = shell.NameSpace(10);

    if (recycleBin.Items().Count == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public bool Empty()
{
    if (IsEmpty() || SHEmptyRecycleBin(IntPtr.Zero, null, 0) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So in another class I am using these functions. I first check if the recycle bin has any items, before we start deleting them. If yes, then delete them. If no, then don't do anything.

However the following happens:
If I have several items to delete, let's say 4. Before the program starts deleting them, a Windows messagebox pops up asking me if I'm sure that I want to delete 4 items. That causes some user interaction in a process that should be fully automated after activation.

I have done some research, but it seems like I can only deactivate that confirmation message on my own pc. Within the recycle bin properties.
I do know that CCleaner for example does empty the recycle bin aswell, without a confirmation popup. So it should be possible.

How can I "skip" this confirmation step in code? I've tried some administrator privileges within the manifest, but it didn't work.

Here is an example of the messagebox:
[image]

If skipping the messagebox is not an option, I would like to know if there is a way to automatically answer the question? If so, I want the program to answer "Yes".
Because if the user presses "No", the SHEmptyRecycleBin function will still return a "success" value, while the items are not removed. So I will have to do a "count" check again after the empty function.

Comment: Show us the code you're using to call `SHEmptyRecycleBin()`

Comment: It was one simple public function. It's added to the code. "public bool Empty()".

Comment: You've ommited to pass the flag `SHERB_NOCONFIRMATION` there `SHEmptyRecycleBin(IntPtr.Zero, null, 0)`

Comment: Yep, that's what it looks like to me too.

Comment: I never used this DLL so I can't be 100% sure, hence a comment instead of an answer. However, [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shemptyrecyclebina) seem clear about it

Comment: Try `SHEmptyRecycleBin(IntPtr.Zero, null, RecycleFlags.SHERB_NOCONFIRMATION)`

Comment: Thank you @Cid and Robert Harvey. That indeed worked. I posted an answer with credits to Cid. If you guys want me to delete it, so you can answer it yourselves, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to pass the right flags in the function call.

I called the function with this:

```
SHEmptyRecycleBin(IntPtr.Zero, null, 0)
```

While it should be this:

```
SHEmptyRecycleBin(IntPtr.Zero, null, RecycleFlags.SHERB_NOCONFIRMATION | RecycleFlags.SHERB_NOPROGRESSUI | RecycleFlags.SHERB_NOSOUND)
```

Credits go to Cid, for answering my question in the comments. Thank you.